# Help Center does not indicate that questions must be useful to more people

Tags: discussion, help-center

The whole point of Stack Overflow is to provide a Q&A of re-usable questions that help everybody.

It's not a helpdesk. A question that is of benefit only to the OP should not be here. It should be downvoted (because it is "not useful") and, in a large number of cases, it can be closed as needing a proper minimal example (because a question with a good MCVE is usually abstract enough to be widely useful, whereas a question with reams of irrelevant code and concepts is *very* specific to the person who wrote that code).

But, since the *"too localised"* close reason was removed (due to abuse, IIRC), the Help Center is really not clear about this. Neither https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic nor https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask actually say any of this, as it turns out. I wasn't aware of this until arguing with someone on Meta about the validity of such one-use-only helpdesk questions, it was pointed out that nowhere on the Help Center actually states this fact of the Stack Exchange model… this is despite the fact that Stack Overflow was created specifically for this purpose.

Could we be clearer in the Help Center as to *why we're here*?

Comment: Many users can't even ask a good question about a specific problem, now you even want them to isolate and generalize the problem. If this would work, I don't know.

Comment: Well, given that you can no longer close a question as 'too localized', it no longer makes much sense to tell users in the Help center that a question should not be too localized.  Fwiw, plenty of SO users ignore this silliness and pick the exact opposite, 'too broad'.  Also the recommendation given by moderators in all previous questions about this.

Comment: @HansPassant: Was the removal of "too localized" _really_ a signal that too localized questions are now acceptable? I don't think that it was. And if your complaint is solely that that's no longer documented anywhere, well, that's mine too, hence this post!

Comment: @Rizier123: I want them to do what they've always been required to do.

Comment: If it's not immediately obvious which close-reason to use, I just take 'too broad' as a catch-all, as suggested by Hans.  If a question is VLQ, I'm not going to waste excessive time on picking the appropriate close reason.  'excessive' is 50ms upwards..

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Why do you think that? Why should he spend any more time on trash then it takes to click?

Comment: @Magisch: You cannot possibly judge something to be "trash" in 50ms. Anyone claiming to do so is criminally negligent and abusing of their powers. No wonder Stack Exchange moderation has an abysmal reputation.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet 50ms is obviously hyperbole. I judge you intelligent to know that. But 1s? Definately. There are so many questions where part of the first sentence read can definately tell you they dont merit a second look.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet okay, I'll bite. One example I just had: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/11758229  From the very first look at that (less then it needs for the dialog to unlock) I can see thats trash. If I didn't want to make this point for you, this question wouldn't have gotten a second look - rightly

Comment: On the topic of isolating and generalizing the problem: 99% of issues on SO would be instantly solved if the askers knew what caused them sufficiently to narrow them down.

Comment: NO, no,  AFTER DECIDING THAT THE QUESTION IS VLQ, I don't want to waste time deciding the correct close-reason.

Comment: For example, more often that I would like, questions are VLQ for multiple reasons.

Comment: That said, it takes very little time indeed to be fairly certain that the time I do spend on reading a question is going to be wasted.   If it starts with 'Consider' or 'Explain', it's 99.9% certain to be a no-effort homework dump.

Comment: here is the problem **too broad** is recommended as the replacement for the semantically diametrically opposed **too localized**. Here is a perfect example, [Write my code for me for this very specific example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192393/bro-ids-searches/36192772#36192772).

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Does the asker have a prayer of understanding the answer? No, because it's not a full-blown tutorial starting from zero: "or good answers would be too long for this format" perfectly explains how "too broad" is right.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if there would be a general statement a la "we aim to help many people with every question" in the help center? Would people then use it as a custom close reason (is this the aim of this question) or would just nothing change except that somewhere something is written? We already have votes for usefulness, I think.

Answer (score 20):

> Stack Overflow was created specifically for this purpose

Yes, it was - a long time ago. Things have changed. [Jaydles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217136) addressed this point two years ago.

> It makes me a tiny bit crazy when I hear someone say, "you can't ask that, because it'll only help you".
>
> Most people - even nice people - who ask a question are extremely focused on the help they need, not the approximate estimate of others in a similar jam.
>
> So, if a question can help one person, someone is willing to answer it, and *it has no other impact on a site, it should be encouraged*.

You may notice that [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217115/is-the-ultimate-goal-of-stack-exchange-really-to-build-a-knowledge-base-for-goog/217136#comment703708_217136) was not really happy about the above statement, but he no longer works here, so...

Comment: I'd like to know whether this is an explicit policy (if so, it would certainly explain a few things — and it was kept _very_ quiet) or just a VP's opinion.

Comment: Perhaps the relevant guidance _either way_ could now be added to the Help Centre? That would settle the debate.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what his job is. My question still stands. Was that a _policy_ or just how he wants things to be?

Comment: Well, this is the kind of statement you could expect from somebody that never once helped anybody at SO, isn't it?  Other than that single spam answer that promotes the company's product.  Everybody loves free beer except those that have to brew it.

Comment: @Hans: Heh! ^_^

Comment: I get the impression the VP of Growth is not your best friend @HansPassant ... any history we should know?

Comment: *...but he no longer works here, so...* question is if we are bound to what employees or former employees think/wants or what the community at large thinks/wants? Have employees not just a vote instead of the vote to decide what the guidance should be?

Comment: @rene About one year ago there were hundreds of votes for bringing back the "lacks minimal understanding" close reason and it didn't happen. So what we are really bound to is the will of the people who run the servers. Everything else is benevolence. If you want to change that, open up your own StackOverflow. The license permits it.

Comment: @Trilarion, yes there is definitely at times a conflicting interest between the company and the community. And I not always agree with or understand the rationale behind decisions, I simply learn to live with the tools and guidance available. I'm a flower, I can bend.

Comment: @rene I just wanted to settle the question you raised. Employees have more than just a vote. You can have an upvoted feature-request and if nobody implements it it's all in vain. In the end, what makes me much more positive towards the whole thing is the license which keeps the content free.

Comment: We can all glean things from the help given to others. Even if specific. The principles can be applied elsewhere and in other contexts.

Answer (score 13):

Where do you draw the line in generalization?

I have learnt a lot on this site from questions that are pretty specific to one user, because while I'm good at abstracting from specific scenarios, I'm awful at making a specific scenario from something abstract.

Different people learn in different ways. Just because a specific question doesn't help you, it doesn't mean the next guy coming along can't glean information from it.

(Obviously situations such as 'I want a program that does x and I have a framework, write the rest for me' should be removed, but someone saying 'I've written this program for myself but I can't find the issue I'm having' is more than fine IMO).

Comment: `I've written this program for myself but I can't find the issue I'm having' is more than fine IMO` - I'd disagree with that statement as written, but could be ok depending on the context.  Someone trying to get someone to debug an entire program by asking "Where's my bug" usually doesn't make a good question.  But someone asking "I get this error in this small snippet and I don't understand why" is a lot more answerable.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Perhaps my phrasing could have been better, but my intention was to say a user can have a program/issue that is highly tailored to them, as long as they describe what it is an identify where it might be then that's fine IMO

Comment: Because someone like me might come along and think 'although he's written it like this, I can recognize this a case of using x function in y programming language, I'm also having issues with this and now that I can see how someone fixed his problem I can now fix mine'.

Comment: As long as the question contained a proper MCVE then yes this can be acceptable. If it doesn't contain a proper MCVE then on balance it's more noise than signal, even if SGR happens to be a really good signal filterer. Note I'm asking about what guidance should go in the Help Centre, not proposing bans or policy shifts or whatever.

Comment: I agree with this answer *iff* it is still valid to close questions as duplicates that describe essentially the same issue, but with a slightly different user-specific test case.

Comment: I think I've answered similar questions in similar ways, that an answer might be very localised or specific but sometimes you stumble on it at the end of a search and it connects some dots for you that find the solution you're looking for. I very much agree with  @SGR 's `someone like me` comment

Answer (score -5):

Clearly it would be extremely difficult to define a "too localized" that is reasonable and is unlikely to be misused.

Even quite localized and well formulated questions (including a MCVE, clearly formulated, not just a typo) can be useful to more people. After all the world is big. Nobody really knows what other people interests or might interest in the future.

That is also the reason why it can be misused. It's just a very subjective category.

And if we don't want "too localized", then clearly we don't need to state that anywhere.

Here an attempt to go in the direction of having a "too localized" reason because I actually see one in relation to certain debugging help questions.

Debugging help questions where a (kind of) MCVE exists and the minimal code example under reasonable effort is still too long are quite unlikely to ever be helpful to anyone else. This is just a statement (true one I think).

Now it could also be a downvote reason (not useful) or even a close reason, but probably not a good comment in the help center, especially if there could indeed be someone who wants to spend the time and answer it (unless we make it into a close reason).

SO is a crossover between a live debugging helpdesk and a programming encyclopedia, it's not only one of them.

I'm personally not very keen on answering the helpdesk questions myself but in doubt I would always vote for the freedom to do so. So the definition of a possible "too localized" close reason would have to be good.

Comment: I could not disagree more. Just because we can't prevent misuse of TL for *closing* because the details can be confusing at the lowest level doesn't mean we should settle for ignoring the *aspiration* of making reusable questions that was key to the site. Keep the aspiration and work toward making it practical as much as possible to live up to it... rather than dropping the aspiration as soon as it gets tough.

Comment: _"Now it could also be a downvote reason (not useful) or even a close reason, but probably not a good comment in the help center"_ This sentence contradicts itself, unless you're proposing we make site policy/convention that is deliberately kept secret for some strange reason.

Comment: _"SO is a crossover between a live debugging helpdesk and a programming encyclopedia, it's not only one of them."_ No!!!