# How to handle "What does this (malicious) obfuscated code do?" questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-delete

Semi-frequently, we get questions asking for help understanding some obfuscated, and likely malicious, code that they have discovered. These questions are rarely of good quality, but then that's partly because obfuscated code is *supposed* to be difficult to unpack and understand.

So while downvoting for lack of research may be appropriate, I cannot locate an appropriate close reason.

- **primarily opinion-based** Nope.
- **too-broad** These scripts aren't usually that elaborate and can be summed up rather quickly.
- **unclear what you're asking** Not if they include everything necessary.
- off-topic

  - **general-computing** Nope.
  - **networking** Nope.
  - **off-site resource** Nope.
  - **debugging help** Nope.
  - **typo** Nope.
- **duplicate of** Can't find any good dupe targets.

So this leaves me questioning, *should* they be closed, as they sometimes are for various reasons?

Often times it's argued that such questions are "too-localized" or "won't help anyone else", but according to the consensus on [Help Center does not indicate that questions must be useful to more people](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319656/help-center-does-not-indicate-that-questions-must-be-useful-to-more-people) (referencing 
[Is the ultimate goal of Stack Exchange really to build a knowledge base for Googlers, not to help individual users (even if they ask good questions)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217115/is-the-ultimate-goal-of-stack-exchange-really-to-build-a-knowledge-base-for-goog)) that reasoning is obsolete.

Arguably it's unnecessary to ever unpack malicious code and it should only be deleted by restoring a backup, but that simply isn't always the case and understanding an attack and what affect it may have had on users can be critical to reversing the damage.

---

Though I'm less-concerned with specific cases than the issue in general, I'll include a recent example for reference:

[Decrypt Javascript Obfuscator [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829846/decrypt-javascript-obfuscator) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4nRl.jpg)) closed as a duplicate of [Javascript eval function decoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720489/javascript-eval-function-decoder)

It was closed by a single dupe-hammer vote for a different questions the closer had answered with an extremely localized answer. Honestly I would argue that dupe target is almost completely worthless as a dupe target and I can't imagine that answer helping anyone but the original question asker. Besides, just telling someone how to partly-unpack some obfuscated code doesn't answer the real and actually important question of understanding what it's doing. This question was deleted before it received the necessary reopen votes though.

---

So back to the question. I'm a rather pedantic question closer who will happily close garbage questions, but even I'm having trouble justifying a close reason for all these questions. Should we close and delete these questions? Should we leave them or potentially even answer them? Is there some canonical duplicate somewhere that I can feel good about using?

**Related:**

There is a related question [How to handle "Explain how this ${code dump} works" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions), however I think the scope of "what does this malicious code do" is significantly less-broad than the noobish question of "explain all this code to me". Only a high-level overview of what malicious code does would ever be useful. The intent of such a question and applicable answers are very different. It's also been suggested this type of question may be better-directed to other Stack Exchange sites, something a typical explain-this-code-dump would not be suitable for.

Comment: What consensus do you see at [Help Center does not indicate that questions must be useful to more people](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319656/)? It's only been viewed 400 times and barely 12% of those viewers voted (the post with the most votes is the question itself, 47 total votes).

Comment: @JoshCaswell Got a better Meta post? The top answer has a pretty strong citation of a SE employee.

Comment: Personally, I agree with the premise of the question, but upvoted [meta's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319663/603977) because it usefully points out previous Meta disagreement, and I read it as a grim retelling of a past mistake. If the score is being interpreted as support for the quoted viewpoint, I guess I'd better change my vote.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Might be better to vote on the original question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217115/is-the-ultimate-goal-of-stack-exchange-really-to-build-a-knowledge-base-for-goog/217136

Comment: Yes, I cast my votes there back when it was first posted.

Comment: If they're not disclosing the fact that it's malicious, then flag it as "Rude or Abusive".

Comment: @AndrewGrimm If it were intended to be run sure, but I've not seen any cases where the OP was trying to spread malware in this way, so I don't think that flag would be appropriate.

Comment: Perhaps these questions could fit on the RE stack exchange?

Comment: @Antimony I hadn't thought of that. That might actually be a good place to direct them. There seems to be a few questions on the topic: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=obfuscated+javascript Want to post an answer?

Comment: Some of thins kind of questions might be appropriate on InformationSecurity : http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/114919/found-suspicious-obfuscated-php-file-is-this-a-hack-attempt-on-my-website/114936

Comment: @gnat Definitely related, but I would say "what does this malicious code do" is significantly less-broad than the noobie question of "explain all this code to me" because only a high-level overview would ever be useful.

Comment: Related question: [Should “Run Snippet” option have a reputation requirement?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321652/should-run-snippet-option-have-a-reputation-requirement-to-prevent-user-s)

Answer (score 55):

Just about any question that is a code dump followed by "explain this" is going to be "Too Broad".  Without the OP going over what they do understand about it, and what they don't understand about it, such a question isn't really answerable in a reasonable scope.

If they *are* asking a sufficiently specific question about the code, such that you can provide a *complete* answer to the question in a few paragraphs or less, then the question is likely fine.  (Assuming it's also clear, as you mentioned.)  That said, I find it very rare for this to be the case.  The vast majority of these types of questions *don't* ask a specific question about the code, so they're Too Broad.

Comment: So something like "It does X using Y in order to accomplish Z" is too-broad? These questions aren't really about analyzing every line of code, just knowing what it does overall to understand what damage may have been done.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Like I said, it's going to depend a lot on the specifics of the question.  If they're not specific about what they want to know, and people are just guessing at what they think the question is asking about, then the question is Too Broad.  If it's clear what they want to know about the question, and that information can be completely answered in a few sentences, then it wouldn't be too broad.

Comment: These questions are *too narrow*. Not sure how to close those under the current rule set since "too narrow" was removed as a reason.

Answer (score 13):

> just telling someone how to partly-unpack some obfuscated code doesn't answer the real and actually important question of understanding what it's doing

Uh, yes, I kind of agree. However, the [actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36829846/3) was "*I need this decrypted can anyone will be able to do it.*" (not even a  question mark), and guessed that closing as a dupe of "how to deobfuscate code" was the best the asker could hope for. Maybe also a comment pointing them to [I found unknown PHP code on my server. How do I de-obfuscate the code?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/115461/8749)/[How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39231/8749).

I think most questions of the kind "*What does this code do?*" are not well-received or even off-topic on Stack Overflow:

- They are too localised, unless they ask (generically) about a common idiom so that they are actually useful for lots of people
- They are too broad, unless they show at least some effort to understand the code and need only a few hints to figure out what is happening at the unclear spots. When these spots are not pointed out in the question, we can't give a clear answer about the little finger, but would need to explain the hand, the banana, the gorilla and the jungle they live in.

Some people try to go for the jungle, but in my opinion we should downvote, vote to close as "too broad" and delete. Stack Overflow is not - or should not be - a place where people can dump some code and yell "Help me, I have no idea".

So if you have an obfuscated, possibly malicious script, there should be two steps and two questions to be asked:

1. "*How to deobfuscate this script?*" which is suitable for answering, or maybe a canonical dupe
2. "*How does this part of malware code work?*" (with the deobfuscated version of the script), which some people might not want to answer but [which is fine in general](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262656/1048572).

Comment: Err, "too localised" is not an off-topic reason, and hasn't been for some time. I linked some Meta posts on this. I also think it's safe to assume those posting these questions aren't looking for help writing malware.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: I'm fine with localised questions that might help only a single user, as long as they are good questions (the one I closed was not). I just think that being localised diminishes your chances of getting a good answer or an answer at all (and bad localised questions often end up in the roomba anyway).

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: I even would support questions that ask for help with writing malware, as long as they are good questions otherwise. It's just that many people shy away from answering them, and explaining how malware works is very similar.

Comment: You write "They are too localized" (which isn't a close reason) or "they are too broad". If this is the case I think just from statistics there should also be a large group of such question which is just right (neither too localized nor too broad).

Answer (score 6):

If the code is thought to be malicious, ethics come into discussion.

I happened to be in the same situation, where I tried to examine a computer virus written in Javascript but highly obfuscated. I was curious to ask about what that virus did and how to find out. Eventually I gave up asking.

I had fear that publicly posting a computer virus's source code could help others build better viruses. But then I ran into the "security by obscurity" concept which is an **anti-pattern**, thus encouraging publishing of virus source code.

Eventually I think that:

- Questions that post part of the code and ask "how do I deobfuscate `${code}` should be on topic
- Questions asking what that code does are on topic as long as they are scoped to a specific fragment of code

About the second point, I want to state that a short, low-level fragment (e.g., manipulation of pointers and attempts to exploit buffer overflows, etc.) that can be summarized in a few lines should always be on topic. An entire pastebin-friendly load of code that is barely readable should be **too broad**, also because readers sometimes consider it difficult to analyze extended fragments of code.

Answer (score 1):

An argument can be made that these are generally not questions "about computer programming", inasmuch as the user asking the question is ultimately not interested in exactly how the obfuscation works or how it exploits their site (or computer), let alone in modifying the obfuscated code in any way. Their concern is more often simply getting a confirmation that it "looks bad".

These questions might be more appropriate on the [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), but even there I suspect that the answer will simply be "it's malicious; wipe and restore from backup". (Which is the right answer, FWIW. Unless you are a security researcher, it's rarely valuable to tear these things apart.)

Comment: I strongly disagree that not understanding what an attack did can always be remedied by "wipe and restore from backup". You don't know if it was a password logger, DOS attacking botnet, DNS reconfigurator, or bitcoin miner. How can you warn your users and take appropriate action when it could have been anything? They really should be concerned with what it did.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara That isn't something that you can usefully determine just by looking at obfuscated JS code. You'd have to download the executable payload and analyze that as well, which falls *way* outside the scope of what SO can reasonably do. (Which is assuming that all parts of the exploit are still live, which they often aren't.)

Comment: This was my first inclination as well. It's a bit like posting "What's this rash on my shin?" over on [Biology.SE], or the stream of "My car started making a weird sound on the highway. What's wrong?" type of flotsam we get on [Mechanics.SE]. It doesn't seem to be about actually _working with_ the topical material.

Comment: Not all exploits contain an additional executable payload. Even if it did, it's not always hard to obtain or even complicated to reverse. If the OP includes all relevant code, I don't think that's a problem.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It would be more-like including a skin sample or offering the answers access to the car to determine the problem.

Comment: The post is still simply a request for diagnosis regardless of the particular material proffered for examination, @AlexanderO'Mara. Other than as a possible demonstration of the procedure of diagnosis, I'm not sure how an answer to that pertains to professional or enthusiast programming practice.

Comment: @JoshCaswell We do have a [tag:reverse-engineering] tag, and reverse-engineering can be something programmers have to do (I've had to do it to diagnose bugs, evaluate exploits, etc.).

Comment: @AlexanderOMara All right, but wouldn't a good [tag:reverse-enginering] question be more than "Found this code: `steal_ur_password()` What is it?" Is a code dump question acceptable because it's not about debugging?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I didn't say these were good questions, just the opposite actually (by all means downvote), but bad-question does not necessitate unanswerable-so-close-and-delete. There's even a badge to highlight this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there exists no close reason for these kind of questions, as they are currently considered on-topic. The best you can do is to down vote them.

Very similar are the many artificial homework questions of the kind "how do I add `x` and `y` without using the + operator", that are of no interest or use to anyone (not even the OP, although they might not realize), yet considered on-topic.

What these questions also have in common is that they make SO a worse site. A site where there is room to study, learn and evolve bad programming practice. Which in turn makes software all around the world worse and less useful for mankind.

I personally don't see why questions leading to bad or harmful practice should be allowed to exist. We used to be able to close these as "too localized" but the crap-huggers here on meta removed that option some years ago. The overall trend of SO has been quantity (traffic/revenue) over quality (content useful for programmers) for many years now.

Comment: s/here on meta/at SE HQ/