# How could I get a question expunged from the site?

Tags: support, specific-question

Here's the question: [Can someone explain what this batch file do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66563666/2128947)

Valuable Answer:

> This asks for elevation, then instructs Windows Defender to skip analyzing *.exe and *.srt files, then decrypts a virus payload and starts it. Boo!

And a comment stating:

> Just search the web for "75095_VTS" and you'll see why it's a bad idea to run arbitrary executables from torrents. Stack Overflow is not the place to reverse engineer batch files

So - it's how to bypass `Defender` and implement a virus.

Now, being a little slow on the uptake as I am, I believe that it's not a really good idea for such information to be made so easily available for use. Sure, the question has been closed - and that is all we mere users appear to be able to do.

AFAIAA, to have the item removed, as I believe it should be, requires the intervention and action of a moderator.

So I flagged the item with a comment "Given the evaluation/answer and comment, this is a virus installer & hence should be squished moderator-like."

The response to which was "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"

Therefore, this *doesn't require moderator intervention* - right? It doesn't need to be deleted (a moderator, not a user privilege). So instead, I've brought the matter to Meta.

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262656/should-questions-about-programming-viruses-and-malware-be-allowed

Comment: Moderators do not judge if a post is potentially illegal or dodgy. What is illegal or dodgy *varies by jurisdiction*, and a *very broad set of actions* can also be legitimate and / or conducted by someone researching 'bad' actions. Knowledge about how viruses work, for example, is not illegal and can _help build defences_. Stack Overflow is not here to censor such information.

Comment: By "expunged", do you mean the standard SE deletion where it's still visible to 10k users, or a hard deletion (which I believe only CMs can do) that erases it from the site completely? You didn't make that clear in your mod flag, and you haven't made it clear in this Meta post either.

Comment: What is "AFAIAA"? IANFWTA..

Comment: As Far as I am Aware, I would say :)

Comment: The question doesn't look harmful at all. [It's not like it wouldn't be documented how to exclude extensions from defender](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/add-mppreference?view=win10-ps)

Comment: @BDL disagree, it does *look* harmful. I understand the red alert, red alert, danger, danger. But don't judge a book by its cover they always say :) It's a question about a batch script doing naughty things, it is not in any way more dangerous than a piece of code about sockets which might also be used to build a virus.

Comment: If anything, it might be good to delete this question since the code is copied and we likely don't have permission of the author to share it. By default, when you encounter code, it's all rights reserved, and the OP states he got it via a torrent which is usually used to share copyrighted material.

Comment: @ErikA:  We're not going to enforce copyright.  The copyright holders can enforce their *own* copyright through a DMCA request.

Comment: @Makoto I imagine this author might be a bit shy about exercising that right, the code being malicious and all. But fair enough

Comment: @ErikA:  I cannot overstate this enough.  Their shyness is not our problem and we take no moderation action based on the *perception* of copyright violations.  It is the exclusive right of the copyright holder to take action, and until such a day comes, we presume that the OP has the rights to post their question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I refrained from closing this question as a dupe of that since it didn't feel like there was any consensus or "general" guidance that could be followed.  Gut tells me that this is one of those relatively rare cases in which a dupe doesn't help the situation or gives misleading guidance.

Comment: @Makoto: I didn't look too closely, I should have (multitasking right now); a similar question was duped to there. I'll add in the original.

Comment: I am trying to assist.  I routinely VTC/VTD any such questions without further analysis.

Comment: I also added [How to handle "What does this (malicious) obfuscated code do?" questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321709)

Answer (score 9):

...wait a minute.

The question is reasonable.

> just out of curiosity can someone briefly explain what this code tries to do and what threat is posseses.

What threat does this code possess is not the worst question to be asking of some dodgy code that someone's come across.

The problem is that this isn't *their* code, and it's a bit awkward to ask a question about "explain this code to me".  However, I would see some value in an expert coming along and explaining what this code does and what the threat level is.

The OP does not appear to intend to hack or compromise any systems, and the question stated is reasonable, if only misguided by their own naivety.  As a user with the privilege of deleting questions I would have a tough time justifying that move, especially with the expert and valuable answer of what it does already there.

Answer (score 0):

> Sure, the question has been closed - and that is all the we mere users appear to be able to do.

No, you can also downvote the question to indicate that it's low quality*, and if you have the delete vote privilege (granted at 10k), you can vote to delete the question if you feel it needs to be removed from the site.

I can't say for sure exactly why the moderator who handled your flag declined it, but the stated reason:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

makes sense. Why should moderators get involved with something that can be handled by regular users? Note that I'm not stating my opinion on whether I think the question should be deleted or not; I'm only pointing out that this is something that can be handled by regular users.

*You could also leave a comment stating the problems with the question, but since comments are liable to be deleted for any number of reasons, this is not a particularly effective strategy.

Comment: Hate to say it but I feel like you've missed the point of this particular question.  You answer the mathematician's question but you don't address anything beneath that which makes this incomplete at best.

Comment: @Makoto That's interesting, I have a similar feeling about your answer (or at least, that you're answering a different aspect of the question). The way the question is phrased, it looks to me like the OP is taking for granted that the question should be deleted, and is asking what the appropriate course of action is, given that their mod flag didn't work. While the linked question probably shouldn't be deleted, I'm simply answering what I see as the OP's intended question, which is, what they should do to expunge such a question if they believe it necessary.